# Consumir servicio POST C# web form

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, webservice, post

Estoy teniendo un problema al consumir un servicio POST, el cual me tiene que devolver una variable. He realizado la prueba desde POSTMAN y se he obtenido resultados, el problema está en como realizo la consulta en el Codebehind. No obtengo ninguna respuesta ni error. Como podría solucionar o consumir de manera correcta el servicio?

/////
LO RESOLVÍ DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA

```
foreach (var item in listaDetalleCompra)
            {
                List<string> productos = new List<string>();
                productos.Add(item.IdProductoPeruShop);
                productos.Add(Convert.ToString(item.Cantidad));
                productos.Add(item.MontoTotalNeto.ToString("N2").Replace(",", "."));
                productos.Add("0");
                productos.Add("0");
                productos.Add(item.IdProductoPeruShop);

                listProductos.Add(productos);
            }

            string serializeProds = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listProductos);

            string prod = serializeProds;

            string url = "http://xxx.cti.lat/yyy/webservices/go.php";
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.QueryString.Add("a", "pCatalogo");
            wc.QueryString.Add("qe", "RED");
            wc.QueryString.Add("tipo", "2");
            wc.QueryString.Add("fpago", "DEPOSITO");
            wc.QueryString.Add("pagado", "0");
            wc.QueryString.Add("ruc", dniComprador);
            wc.QueryString.Add("v", local);
            wc.QueryString.Add("c", localORG);
            wc.QueryString.Add("d", apodo);
            wc.QueryString.Add("dir_ruc", direccionComprador);
            wc.QueryString.Add("log", "CREAVIR");
            wc.QueryString.Add("not", not);
            wc.QueryString.Add("delivery", "0");
            wc.QueryString.Add("dir", dir);
            wc.QueryString.Add("ubi", ubi);
            wc.QueryString.Add("ref", refe);
            wc.QueryString.Add("prod", prod);

            var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", wc.QueryString);

            var responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

            idop = responseString;
```

Comment: Coloca código en lugar de imágenes, por favor. Gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso lo siguiente y me va muy bien.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es añadir el paquete NuGet "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" a tu proyecto.

Luego se utiliza `HttpClient` para realizar la petición pero con la extensión `HttpClientExtensions` que te permite utilizar el método `PostAsJsonAsync` que facilita mucho la vida, ya que sólo hay que terminar de componer la url y pasarle el objeto que quieres serializar como Json. Te dejo una clase de ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WinFrmReferenciaExterna
{
    public class ConsumirPost
    {
        public async Task<string> Lanzar(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62221/"),
                };
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage respuesta = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Values", obj).Result;
                if (respuesta.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // La respuesta es correcta y por ejemplo la retorno como string
                    return await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ERROR : {ex.Message}");
            }

            return "KO";
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que veo estas enviando la información pero no por POST.

Proba utilizando una colección `NameValueCollection` para que el script de PHP lo pueda tomar con la variable $_POST y no utilizar un string json (en php estas usando un framework en particular o simplemente PHP directo?)

Te dejo un ejemplo

```
var url = "url.php";
var col = new NameValueCollection();
col.Add("param1", "value1");
col.Add("param2", "value2");
var responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", col);
var responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes);
```

**Update 18/Jun**

En base a tu codigo, utilice `HttpClient` en vez de `WebClient`. Te dejo el ejemplo que arme

```
private string ObtenerIdopCompra(string dniComprador, string locall, string localORG, string apodo, string direccionComprador, string not1, string dir1, string ubi1, string referen, List<DetalleCompra> listaDetalleCompra)
{
    List<List<string>> productoJSON = new List<List<string>>();

    foreach (var item in listaDetalleCompra)//22 y 56
    {
        List<string> productos = new List<string>();
        productos.Add("4");
        productos.Add(Convert.ToString(item.Cantidad));
        productos.Add(item.MontoTotalNeto.ToString("N2").Replace(",", "."));
        productos.Add("1");
        productos.Add("0");
        productos.Add("4");

        productoJSON.Add(productos);
    }

    string apiUrl = "http://aaa.cti.lat/aa2/webservices/xyz.php";
    object input = new
    {
        a = "pCatalogo",
        canal = "RED",
        tipo = "2",
        fpago = "DEPOSITO",
        pagado = "0",
        ruc = dniComprador,
        local = locall,
        localorg = localORG,
        razon = apodo,
        dir_ruc = direccionComprador,
        log = "CREAVIR",
        not = not1,
        delivery = "0",
        dir = dir1,
        ubi = ubi1,
        refe = referen,
        prod = productoJSON
    };

    string inputJson = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(input);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(
        apiUrl, 
        new StringContent(inputJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        ).Result;

    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Como podes ver, la parte que cambio es la forma en que se llaman al servicio externo que ahora es por medio de `HttpClient`.

Comment: El servicio que estoy consumiendo es de un proveedor externo que desarrolla en php, pero yo consumo ese servicio desde C# en .net. al poner el codigo que me muestras no me permite colocar el New Text.

Comment: Hola Antonio,a que te refieres con el `New Text`, no comprendo

Comment: var responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes); a esa linea

Comment: Que error te muestra? Agregaste el `using System;` al inicio del archivo? y ademas agregada la dll `System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll`?

Comment: Añadí una imagen de los errores

Comment: Hola, para eliminar el ultimo error puedes utilizar `var responsebody = (new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()).GetString(responsebytes);`
Con respecto al error de la linea que tiene `client.UploadValues`, la propiedad client es un objeto de la clase `WebClient` que creas en tu codigo

Comment: Hola, agregue un nuevo código en mi respuesta, espero que te sea de utilidad, sino cualquier cosa avisa.